# Illustrator vector nondestructive actions destroying

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm having a very strange problem with Illustrator CS5. When I'm doing non-destructive actions, such as eye-dropper or selecting and dragging, the points in my compound object are shifting around.

[image]

The only thing that I did between those two halves of the picture was an eye-dropper tool. What on earth is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the objects, then uncheck "**Align to Pixel Grid**" on the **Transform Panel**.

If you don't see "Align to Pixel Grid" on the Transform Panel, click the Transform Panel Menu and choose `Show Options`.

Comment: You're a life-saver!